# Laravel x-editable CRSF Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I followed documentation and another support article however I am still stuck. I want to be able to edit a field with x-editable.

- I used what they said on [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/x-editable-csrf-token-mismatch?page=0)
- I have CSRF meta tag in view file

I am getting the error;

```
UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

Js.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
 'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});

$(document).ready(function() {


//toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';


$.fn.editable.defaults.params = function (params) {
   params._token = $("meta[name=token]").attr("content");
   return params;
};

$.fn.editable.defaults.send = 'always';

  //make parking editable
  $('#parking').editable();
});
```

Comment: _The Response content must be a string or object_ Are you returning Boolean from server?

Comment: Check the response you return from your controller. Or post the code here.

Comment: @EddyTheDove Controller;      public function quickupdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
      
      $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
       $name = $request->get('name');
       $value = $request->get('value');
       $event->$name = $value;
       return $event->save();
    }

Comment: @Tushar I'm not sure I pasted my controller above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, do

```
public function quicUpdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    ...
    $event->save();
    return response()->json($event); //This will return the whole event object
}
```

Comment: Thank you, before I used this controller code linked from the documentation of x-editable does this mean theirs is wrong?

Comment: I have no idea about their controller. WHen you return to view return in JSON.